# Maven dependency on other Maven projects

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I have multiple maven projects, to add dependencies between them I just add it to the POM, for example :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.company</groupId>
        <artifactId>XMLManagement</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

I am working with eclipse, and everything runs and works great until I try to release a jar.

**Problem1: ** Maven throws an error because it can't find the jars of the other maven projects it depends on in the local repository,
and this means that I have to figure out myself the dependencies between the projects, and go to each and every project in the right order and run "mvn clean install"

This does not seem logical since that is the main purpose of maven, there must be a way to tell maven to do it himself.

**Problem2: ** If project A depends on B that depends on C, and I want to use C in A then in eclipse its enough that I added B in the POM of A and it works, but when I run "mvn clean install" maven throws an error that it is missing dependency of C.
This means I have to add the dependency between A and C, which doesn't make sense because in eclipse I already see it under "Maven Dependencies", so if eclipse recognizes it why mvn clean install doesn't?

Note that I am able to produce the jar I need at the end, but only after a lot of hard work as described above.

I know I can use something like nexus or artifactory, but it's an overkill for me and I want to be able to do it in local repository.

I am looking for the proper way to do it, any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have an internal repository where you put all the artefacts?

Comment: I have my local repository in C:\Users\giladba\.m2\repository

Comment: And the artefacts and poms are located in this local repository?

Comment: Yes but only after I run mvn clean install on all the projects in the right order

Comment: What you need is your own maven repository like Nexus and this must be configured in your pom. And all your Projects must put there artefacts there

Comment: I know I can use something like nexus or artifactory, but it's an overkill for me and I want to be able to do it in a plain local repository.

Comment: It is not possible.How your artefacts should come to your local repository if you do not want to build it?

Comment: I want maven to "mvn clean install" them for me in the correct order

Comment: Then you have to make a Multi module build

Comment: @Jens works like a charm, many thanks :)

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is a top-level pom that lists each of the things you want build as modules. In maven jargon, this is known as a [reactor build](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html).

Something like:

---

```
 <groupId>this.that</groupId>
 <artifactId>build.root</artifactId>
 <name>A name</name>
 <packaging>pom</packaging>
 <modules>
  <module>../a.b</module>
  <module>../a.c</module>
```

Comment: OK so I created a new maven project with the POM as you described, and when I run mvn clean install and it worked perfect! many thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, find your file **settings.xml** configure path repository how:

```
<localRepository>E:\repositoryMavem</localRepository>
```

- Hability your Eclipse (or IDE in use) for this file *settings.xml*
- After go to path your project has pom.xml
- run de command

```
 mvn install:install-file -Dfile=E:\repositoryMavem\XMLManagement-1.0.jar -DgroupId=com.company -DartifactId=XMLManagement -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

- if you want to use IDE Eclipse (you can).
- if run clean for artifact, you need run install again

Comment: already did that before I posted the question, it works but its a lot of work to mvn install all the projects in the correct order.